# Make UIView go out of bounds but still be visiable

Tags: ios

I need a UIView to go out of the superviews bounds but still be visiable. If I move it out of bounds it is cut out.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that the superview has `clipsToBounds` set to `true`. Here's what Apple's documentation says about the property:

> A Boolean value that determines whether subviews are confined to the
>   bounds of the view.
>
> Discussion Setting this value to YES causes subviews to be clipped to
>   the bounds of the receiver. If set to NO, subviews whose frames extend
>   beyond the visible bounds of the receiver are not clipped. The default
>   value is NO.

To have subviews outside the bounds visible, try `myView.clipsToBounds = false`

Comment: I have clipsToBounds = NO but it still is cut when I move it slightly out of bounds.

Comment: Do you have a screenshot? Is the view hierarchy being set up in code or Interface Builder?

Comment: My super view has a backgroundColor of black, while my subview is a UIImageView and the UIImageView is cut in half when I want it to be able to be fully seen.